# A peculiar behaviour of the residuals from a GLS model in R

Tags: r, regression, generalized-least-squares

I have a data set which contains the following:

IV.1: first independent variable with 4 levels (one, two, three, four)
IV.2: an independent variable with 4 levels (elm.one, elm.two, elm.three, elm.four)
time: an independent variable (days) with four levels (7, 15, 21, 30)
DV: dependent (response) variable (continuous)

The data set contains duplicate measurements of the response (DV) for each IV.1, IV.2, time combination (128 data points in total).

The data set looks like this:

```
    IV.1     DV.  IV.2 time
    elm.one  331  one     7   
    elm.one  479  one     7  
    elm.one  154  one    15  
    elm.one  169  one    15  
    elm.one  56   one    21  
    elm.one  27   one    21
```

I fit the following generalised least square model in R using `gls` from the "nlme" package (following the Zuur et al. 2009 procedure):

`model <- gls(DV ~IV.1*time,
             weights = varIdent(form= ~ 1|IV.1*time),
             data=myData)`

I tried different variance structures `(~1|IV.1)` and `(~1|time)` but they give higher AIC and BIC scores.

The alarming thing about this model is its validation plots:

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not entirely sure about your terminology: generalized linear model (GLM) and generalized least squares (GLS) are not quite the same. The function `gls` does not even do GLS estimation (as per textbook definition of GLS) but instead uses maximum likelihood. (Not that this would be a helpful note...)

Comment: @utobi what I want is to analyse the significance of the IV.1 and time effects on the DV. I cannot apply ANOVA because the normality and variance homogeneity assumptions are violated.

Comment: @utobi No, I have not. At least not before knowing what's wrong with my current analysis. Checking the logistic regression, it seems appropriate when the dependent variable is dichotomous (binary): http://www.statisticssolutions.com/what-is-logistic-regression/ .

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your model, I thought you where modelling IV.2.

Comment: What is `E`? Your variance structure appears to be hugely over-parameterized. Please provide a plot of `DV ~ time` colored by `IV.1` (or, even better, provide your data).

Comment: @Roland the E is normalised residuals. I have updated the question and added a plot of E vs. time.

Comment: something is wrong here, but you don't provide sufficient information. Show your raw data.